# Escaping (, round brackets sybase SQL

Tags: sql, escaping, wildcard, sybase, parentheses

I am working with Sybase SQL and want to exclude all entries that look like this:

(NOT PRESENT)

So I tried using:

`SELECT col FROM table WHERE col NOT LIKE '(%)'`

Do you guys know what is happening? I think I need to escap ( somehow, but I do not know how. The following returns an error:

`SELECT col FROM table WHERE col NOT LIKE '\(%\)' ESCAPE '\'`

Kind Regards

Comment: What went wrong with your first attempt? It works for me...

Comment: It is ignored. Rows containing "(NOT PRESENT)" are still kept.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

SELECT col FROM table WHERE col NOT LIKE ('(%)')

Answer (score 0):

You might find this helpful

[Sybase Event Stream Processor 5.0 CCL Programmers Guide - String Functions](http://infocenter.sybase.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.sybase.infocenter.dc01612.0500/doc/html/swa1292617706573.html)

> **like()**
>
> Scalar. Determines whether a given string matches a specified pattern string.
>
> **Syntax**
>
> `like ( string, pattern )`
>
> **Parameters**
>
> `string` A string.
> `pattern` A pattern of characters, as a string. Can contain wildcards.
>
> **Usage**
>
> Determines whether a string matches a pattern string. The function returns 1 if the string matches the pattern, and 0 otherwise. The pattern argument can contain wildcards: '_' matches a single arbitrary character, and '%' matches 0 or more arbitrary characters. The function takes in two strings as its arguments, and returns an integer.
>
> Note: In SQL, the infix notation can also be used: sourceString like patternString.
>
> **Example**
>
> `like ('MSFT', 'M%T')` returns 1.